# Need to press cancel button twice before it will go to previous view controller

Tags: swift

When I use camera in my app I want to check if user clicked on the cancel button but when I use this code I will need to press the cancel button 2 times before it will run `_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` but when I try to replace it with `print("hello")` it works and I only need to press the cancel button once. what method can I do to fix this issue?

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do not assign the output? Just do  navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) and tell us if that makes a differents.

Comment: @Milander I have just tried it and I will need to press on the cancel button for 3 times instead. the answer Sh_Khan give works. it seems like I need to hide the picker first.

Comment: Seems logic. Sorry that my answer didn't work, but im glad that Sh_Khan did found the solution :)

Comment: @Milander It's fine, and thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to hide the picker also

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
    picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
      self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```